# Alertify prompt not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alertify

I recently grabbed a copy of the `Alertify` library but I can't get `prompt` to work.

My app is .NET MVC using Bootstrap.

This is a snip of my my html (removed most of the option tags for visibility):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Model
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id='selmodels' class='w250' type='model'><option class='w250' value='0'></option></select>
        &nbsp;
        <div id="edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script (this was different but changed to the alertify example while debugging):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#edit').click(function () {
        //var name = $('#selmodels option:selected').text();
        alertify.prompt('This is a prompt dialog!', 'some value',
            function(evt, value) { alertify.message('You entered: '  + value); }
        );
        return false;
    });
})
```

However clicking 'Edit' gives the error:

> fn must be a function

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you've used incorrect order for the arguments of the prompt method of alertify. The correct template is as follows:

```
alertify.prompt('Insert your message here:', function (e, str) {
        if (e) {
            // e corresponds to an "OK" press.
            // str is the value of the prompt textbox.
        } else {
            // else corresponds to a "Cancel" press.
        }
    }, 'Insert the default textbox message here.');
```

So just change the order of your arguments in the prompt method. Your code in the end should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#edit').click(function () {
      //var name = $('#selmodels option:selected').text();
      alertify.prompt('This is a prompt dialog!',
          function(evt, value) { alertify.message('You entered: '  + value); }
          'some value'
      );
      return false;
  });
})
```

Comment: You are right. The example at http://alertifyjs.com/prompt.html is wrong! Thanks :)